# semantic release - TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-release

I am trying to publish a package from my app.
I get this error at the publish step:

```
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 18.0.0
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/github"
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "analyzeCommits" from "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "generateNotes" from "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/github"
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/github"
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "success" from "@semantic-release/github"
[2:28:46 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "fail" from "@semantic-release/github"
[2:28:47 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "fail" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"
[2:28:47 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/github] › ℹ  Verify GitHub authentication (https://api.github.com)
[2:28:48 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  Failed step "fail" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"
[2:28:48 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  An error occurred while running semantic-release: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/@semantic-release/github/lib/get-fail-comment.js:19:10)
    at module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/@semantic-release/github/lib/fail.js:28:74)
    at async fail (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/@semantic-release/github/index.js:64:3)
    at async validator (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/normalize.js:34:24)
    at async /home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/pipeline.js:37:34
    at async /home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/pipeline.js:31:3
    at async Object.pluginsConf.<computed> [as fail] (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/index.js:80:11)
    at async callFail (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:235:7)
    at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:264:7)
    at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5) {
  pluginName: '@semantic-release/github'
}
[2:28:48 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  ERELEASEBRANCHES The release branches are invalid in the `branches` configuration.
A minimum of 1 and a maximum of 3 release branches are required in the branches configuration (https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#branches).

This may occur if your repository does not have a release branch, such as master.

Your configuration for the problematic branches is [].

AggregateError: 
    SemanticReleaseError: The release branches are invalid in the `branches` configuration.
        at module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/get-error.js:6:10)
        at /home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/branches/index.js:44:19
        at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
        at module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/branches/index.js:34:46)
        at async run (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:57:22)
        at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:260:22)
        at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5)
    at module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/branches/index.js:66:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async run (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:57:22)
    at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:260:22)
    at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/testapp2/testapp2/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5)npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! rezassgtest@0.0.0-development semantic-release: `semantic-release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the rezassgtest@0.0.0-development semantic-release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have changed the name of the application to lower-case because I thought that was the problem but no luck.
Can you guide me on where I should look for this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. No solution for me yet, either. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71896623/semantic-release-fails-on-github-authentication-failed-step-fail-of-plugin

Answer (score 1):

In my .releaserc.json file, I had the branch configuration as:

```
{
  "branch": "main",
  "plugins": [
  ...
```

I renamed the branch to master and pushed:

```
git branch -m main master
git push origin -u master
```

And the error went away. semantic-release has problems with the new default main branch for repos, according to this issue:

https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/issues/2567

Comment: Thank you, dude, this also solved it for me