# Semantic-Release fails on GitHub authentication: Failed step "fail" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, cicd, semantic-release

I am trying to integrate `semantic-release` into my Node CI/CD workflow. I have tried following the documentation and tutorials but I am clearly missing something. The testing step passes, but the publish step fails at "Run npx semantic release".

This is the YML script I am using:

```yaml
name: Test and Release CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  test:

    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
        os: [ubuntu-latest]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm test

  publish:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: [test]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js 16.x
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: "16.x"
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npx semantic-release
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        NPM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

Here is the error from the Github action:

```
Run npx semantic-release
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 19.0.2
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "verifyConditions" from "@semantic-release/github"
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "analyzeCommits" from "@semantic-release/commit-analyzer"
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "generateNotes" from "@semantic-release/release-notes-generator"
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "prepare" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "publish" from "@semantic-release/github"
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/npm"
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "addChannel" from "@semantic-release/github"
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "success" from "@semantic-release/github"
[5:46:35 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Loaded plugin "fail" from "@semantic-release/github"
[5:46:36 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Start step "fail" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"
[5:46:36 PM] [semantic-release] [@semantic-release/github] › ℹ  Verify GitHub authentication (https://api.github.com)
[5:46:36 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  Failed step "fail" of plugin "@semantic-release/github"
[5:46:36 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  An error occurred while running semantic-release: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/@semantic-release/github/lib/get-fail-comment.js:19:10)
    at module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/@semantic-release/github/lib/fail.js:28:74)
    at async fail (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/@semantic-release/github/index.js:64:3)
    at async validator (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/normalize.js:34:24)
    at async /home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/pipeline.js:37:34
    at async /home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/pipeline.js:31:3
    at async Object.pluginsConf.<computed> [as fail] (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/plugins/index.js:80:11)
    at async callFail (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:243:7)
    at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:272:7)
    at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5) {
  pluginName: '@semantic-release/github'
}
[5:46:36 PM] [semantic-release] › ✖  ERELEASEBRANCHES The release branches are invalid in the `branches` configuration.
A minimum of 1 and a maximum of 3 release branches are required in the branches configuration (https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#branches).

This may occur if your repository does not have a release branch, such as master.

Your configuration for the problematic branches is [].

AggregateError: 
    SemanticReleaseError: The release branches are invalid in the `branches` configuration.
        at module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/get-error.js:6:10)
        at /home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/branches/index.js:44:19
        at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
        at module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/branches/index.js:34:46)
        at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
        at async run (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:65:22)
        at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:268:22)
        at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5)
    at module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/lib/branches/index.js:66:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async run (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:65:22)
    at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/index.js:268:22)
    at async module.exports (/home/runner/work/Alphanumeric-Encoder/Alphanumeric-Encoder/node_modules/semantic-release/cli.js:55:5)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have successfully published using the `NPM_TOKEN` from this project during other troubleshooting, so I know that isn't the problem. I believe the issue might be with the GitHub authentication token, but for the life of me I'm stumped. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. How do I correct this error?

**EDIT** - Related: [semantic release - TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098101/semantic-release-typeerror-cannot-read-property-name-of-undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default config assumes branch `master`, so if you're using `main` you'll get that `ERELEASEBRANCHES` error.

You can try setting the `.releaserc.js` file (or the `release` property in `package.json`) with that branch instead.

```
"branches": ["main", "next"]
```

Docs for the config are at https://semantic-release.gitbook.io/semantic-release/usage/configuration

There's a PR for adding main as a fallback default branch, but it's not merged yet.

Comment: That solved it, thanks! I closed my issue there and linked it to the one you mentioned.

Comment: I have the same exact issue and set my branches to `["main"]` but still get the same error